# Determine that the languages accepted by two NFA's are same or not

Tags: nfa

I have two **NFA**'s.
I need to determine whether both recognize the same language
I would be much obliged if anyone could be so kind enough to explain how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a canonical representation of an NFA by computing its equivalent **minimal** DFA.
If two NFA's have the same canonical representation, they accept the same language.